# Which column to use in my form to upload 1 or more pictures to my item?

Tags: image, image-upload

I am using sharepoint 2013. I have a custom list with a custom contenttype. Which column do I need to use to make it possible to upload 1 or more pictures to my item?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, for uploading images you have to use `Hyperlink or Picture` type of column.

Comment: This column type is asking for a url, I cannot upload a picture.

Comment: Yes, it will. Your picture can be stored in site assets and then you can point the url to site assets.

Comment: yes, but thats to much work for my end users. They need first upload the picture in the site assets library. After this they need to get the url of the picture. And at the end they need to paste the url in the column with type "Hyperlink or Picture". Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple pictures to be linked with a single item.. You should do the opposite, take a Picture Library and a Lookup column to your Meta Item to which you want to link.

Comment: If I implement this scenario, it is possible to select an existing picture. But the pictures will be available in the view as hyperlinks and not as pictures!

Comment: True, you will need to develop custom view maybe Visual Web Part to show the pictures..